# Sheet doesn't recalculate after picking from list including own function

Tags: excel, vba, function, validation

I have workbook with user VBA function (returning name of the cell):

```
Function cellName()
    cellName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Name.Name
    
End Function
```

I have a list *dictList* with 3 columns used as dictionary (cellNames; ENG equivalents; CZ equivalents)

I have a cell *$P$1* including data validation that can contain EN/CZ value.

Each cell in the sheet that has specified name (=cellName) includes a function

```
=VLOOKUP(cellName();dictList;IF($P$1="CZ";2;3);FALSE)
```

Finally each named cell contains text in czech or english language based on its name and vlooked value in dictlist.

The problem occurs, when I switch in *$P$1* from CZ to EN or vice versa.

The values with VLOOKUP formulas shows result *#VALUE!* until I press F2 and Enter on each cell.

I don't want to press F2+enter on each cell after switching the language.

Tank you for your help.

Karel

When I put the result of cellName() directly to vlookup, then it works as expected. When I put there back my function, then it returns the #VALUE! again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ActiveCell`, use [`Application.ThisCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thiscell):

> Returns the cell in which the user-defined function is being called from as a `Range` object.

```
Public Function cellName() As String
    cellName = Application.ThisCell.Name.Name
End Function
```